# How to use LocalStorage to make checkboxes persist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

How can we make the checkboxes persist for a user even when he reloads the page?

Please if you have the Javascript expertise can you help me with the relevant AJAX calls or give me some further guidance so I can pursue the answer on my own.

Every three boxes the user checks a new set of three boxes will show. How can we keep these AJAX induced boxes from disappearing?

[image]

**habits/_form.html.erb**

```
<label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id"> Missed: </label>
<% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
  <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
    <p>
      <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id"> Level <%= index + 1 %>: </label>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
   </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**habit.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var handleChange = function() {
    habit = $(this).parent().prev().attr("id");
    level = $('label', $(this).parent()).attr("id");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
        method: "POST"
      });
      localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, true);
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
        method: "DELETE"
      });
      localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, true);
    }
    if (!$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', $(this).parent()).length) {
      /* this is just an example, you will have to ammend this */
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(".habit-check").on('change',handleChange);
    }
  }
  $(".habit-check").on('change',handleChange);
});
```

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

    def current_level_strike
      levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
          def committed_wdays
            committed.map do |day|    
              Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
            end
          end

          def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
              committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.missed_days
          end     

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            6
        end
    end
  end
```

**days_missed_controller**

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end

  def destroy
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
    habit.save
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end
end
```

Here's the **gist** of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

Please let me know if you need any further explanation, code, or pictures. **Thank you** so much for your time!

Comment: much easier to use localStorage to store one big object or array for something like this than it is to store each element in it's own localStorage key. You then use JSON.parse() to convert the whole array on page load and can iterate over it. To save use JSON.stringify()

Comment: Can you please please @charlietfl provide an answer below so I can finally fix this solution because I don't know javascript on my own and I'm relying on a few specific problems beyond my scope of knowledge before I can launch my app I've been working all year on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, shouldnt one of the setItem calls on localstorage set checkbox value to false

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
        method: "POST"
      });
      localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, true);
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
        method: "DELETE"
      });
      localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, false);//<--- ? ?
    }
```

i made a quick fiddle to show how you can pass objects into localStorage, and load them later.

When you first load the page, check if user has something saved, if so, skip ajax requests etc, and simply create the rows based on the info on localStorage.

http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/s39c9fws/18/

```
<div id="container">
<div class="row" id="row_1">
    <span class="label">Row 1:</span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="check_1" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="check_2" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="check_3" value="1" />
</div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="clear saved values" onclick="localStorage.setItem('checkbox_rows', false)"/>

<input type="button" value="add new row" onclick="addNewRow()"/>


var saveChecks = function() {
    var rows = $(".row"), saveObj = [], alreadySavedRows = localStorage.getItem("checkbox_rows");
    if ( alreadySavedRows ) {alreadySavedRows = JSON.parse(alreadySavedRows);}
    console.log("saveChecks", rows.length);
    if ( alreadySavedRows && alreadySavedRows.length ) {saveObj = alreadySavedRows;}
    var replacePreviousRow = function(row_obj) {
        var i;
        for ( i = 0; i < saveObj.length; i++ ) {
            if ( saveObj[i].row_id == row_obj.row_id ) {
               // console.log("replaced previous", row_obj);
                saveObj[i] = row_obj;return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    $.each(rows, function( key, val ) {
        var 
            checks = $(val).find("input[type='checkbox']"),
            rowObj = {"row_id": $(val).attr("id"), "checkboxes": []};
        ;
        rowObj.label = $(val).find(".label").text();
        $.each(checks, function( key, check ) {
            check= $(check);
            rowObj.checkboxes.push({
                check_id: check.attr("id"), 
                checked: check.prop('checked'),
                value: check.attr("value")
            });
        });
        // console.log("rowObj before", rowObj);
        if ( !replacePreviousRow(rowObj ) ) { saveObj.push(rowObj);}


    });
    //console.log("saveObj", saveObj);
    localStorage.setItem( "checkbox_rows",  JSON.stringify(saveObj) );
}
var container = $("#container");
var loadChecks = function() {
    var rows = localStorage.getItem("checkbox_rows"), i, j, row, check, rowElem, checkElem;
    if ( !rows ) {return false;}
    rows = JSON.parse(rows);
    if ( !rows || !rows.length ) {return false;}
    //console.log("rows:", rows);

    for ( i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
        row = rows[i];
        //remove any previously existing rows
        $("#" + row.row_id).remove();
        rowElem = $("<div class='row'></div>");
        rowElem.attr("id", row.row_id);
        container.append(rowElem);
        rowElem = $("#" + row.row_id );
        rowElem.append("<span class='label'>"+row.label+"</span>");
        for ( j = 0; j < row.checkboxes.length; j++ ) {
            check = row.checkboxes[j];
            checkElem = $("<input type='checkbox' name='test'/>");
            checkElem.attr("id", check.check_id);
            rowElem.append(checkElem);
            checkElem = $("#" + check.check_id);
            checkElem.attr("id", check.check_id);
            checkElem.attr("value", check.value);
            checkElem.prop("checked", check.checked);

        }
    }
}

window.addNewRow = function() {
    var rowElem = $("<div class='row'></div>"), i, row_id, checkElem;
    row_id = Math.round(1000*Math.random());
    rowElem.attr("id", "row_" + row_id );
    rowElem.append("<span class='label'>Row id:" + row_id +"</span>");
    for (i = 0; i < Math.ceil( Math.random() * 10 ); i++ ) {
        checkElem = $("<input type='checkbox' name='test' />");
        checkElem.attr("id", "check_" + row_id + "_" + i );
        checkElem.val(i);
        rowElem.append(checkElem);
    }
    container.append(rowElem);
    setTimeout(saveChecks, 100);
}

$().ready(function() {
    console.log("ready");
    setTimeout( loadChecks, 30);
    $("body").on("click", ".row", function(evt) {
        var row = $(evt.currentTarget), notChecked = row.find("input:not(:checked)").length, id;
        console.log("evt",notChecked);
        if ( !notChecked ) {
            id = Math.ceil( 1000 * Math.random() );
            row.append("<input type='checkbox' name='test' id='check_"+id+"' value='1' />");
        }
        saveChecks();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for this well thought out answer! I tried the fiddle and in my code Rainer to no avail. In the fiddle once all three boxes are checked in a row no new checkboxes are generated so I can't test out if those generated checkboxes would remain by refreshing the page. I added your code to the bottom of habit.js and switched true to false (because I think you're right), but the generated boxes continued to disappear upon reloading the page. Thank you so so much for your help though @Rainer.

Comment: I updated the fiddle.

It shows how you can add rows, and load them.
The basic thing you need, is just...loading/saving json objects. The rest you can easily figure out yourself.

Comment: Yea I took a look at your fiddle and it made me more confused than before.      I'm not trying to add new rows, but new checkboxes in a row (`current_level`) So for example each level begins by showing 3 checkboxes. If the user checks all three checkboxes 3 new checkboxes will show horizontally next to it. That worked prior. Just getting the newly generated checkboxes to persist upon refreshing the page is the problem. Is that what your code does Rainer?  I don't know JSON so hopefully I can easily figure it out as a beginner from there.

Comment: It doesnt really matter if you add a new checkboxes, or an entire new row, the point is how you save and load them. If you know how to save a row, then you also know how to save a checkbox. I made another quick update to the fiddle. It now adds a checkbox when user checks all the checkboxes, so there is always an empty checkbox available. and those new checkboxes get saved too.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! With no understanding of javascript how long do you think it would take me to understand how to fix this problem? Do you suggest any courses/books/tutorials/articles first? Should I focus on learning javascript, AJAX, JSON, jquery to find the solution. I kind of get confused by the similarities and don't know where to start.

Comment: JavaScript is the easiest language to learn, and what you have already posted yourself, shows that you already know enough to solve that problem in less than an hour. 
My example shows everything you need to know.